# How to set a minimum height for a div and make it stretch only if needed?

Tags: html, css

Suppose that I have a content `div` like this:

```
<div id="content">
</div>
```

I would like to know if it is possible with CSS to style this `div` to have a minimum height (let's say 700px, for example) and all the content that is placed inside this `div` will only stretch (making its height longer) the `div` if the sum of the height of its content is greater than the div's height.

I tried using the `min-height` attribute, but it simply didn't work. All content that I place inside the `div` makes it longer.

**UPDATE**

This is some page of my application with the css files (the id of the content div in the css files is `conteudo`) Unfortunatelly my code is not in English, but I think this is irrelevant. If you can spot the bug why the `min-height` attribute is not working:

**acessonegado.xhtml**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head id="j_idt2">
        <title>Grupos de E-mail de Servidores</title>
        <link href="resources/css/gruposemailservidores.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/layout.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
        <link href="resources/css/acessonegado.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /></head><body>
        <div id="cabecalho">
            <img src="resources/img/ufca.png" alt="Universidade" />
            <span>Grupos de E-mail de Servidores</span>
        </div>
<form id="form" name="form" method="post" action="/gruposemailservidores/acessonegado.xhtml" enctype="application/x-www-form-urlencoded">
<input type="hidden" name="form" value="form" />

            <div id="usuario">
                <div>
                    ADMIN<br />UNIVERSIDADE
                </div>
            </div>

            <div id="barraTitulo">Acesso Negado
<a href="#" title="Sai do Grupos de E-mail de Servidores">Sair</a>
            </div>

            <div id="conteudo">
        <p>Este aplicativo é de uso exclusivo de servidores da</p>
        <p>COORDENADORIA DE INFRAESTRUTURA DE TI</p>
            </div><input type="hidden" name="javax.faces.ViewState" id="j_id1:javax.faces.ViewState:0" value="-8939669570174810183:-4107362002777505590" autocomplete="off" />
</form>

        <div id="rodape">
            <p>aaaaaaaaaaaaa</p>
            <p>bbbbbbbbbbbbb</p>
        </div></body>
</html>
```

**gruposemailservidores.css**

```
body
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: verdana, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 70%;
}

#cabecalho
{
    height: 84px;
    background-color: #dde8df;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #6f9b76;
}

#cabecalho img
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 4px;
    left: 10px;
}

#cabecalho span
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 23px;
    left: 145px;
    font-family: trebuchet ms, arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 240%;
    font-weight: bold;
    color: rgba(0, 83, 83, 0.8);
    text-shadow: 2px 8px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0px -5px 35px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.3);
}

#rodape
{
    font-size: 90%;
    color: white;
    background-color: #6f9b76;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 0;
}

#rodape p
{
    margin: 0;
}

#rodape p:first-child
{
    margin-bottom: 2px;
}

input, select, textarea, button
{
    font-family: inherit;
    font-size: 100%;
}

input[type="submit"], input[type="button"]
{
    border: 1px solid;
}

.ui-dialog
{
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
    -moz-box-shadow: 5px 5px 5px #888;
}

.ui-dialog #iconeAlerta
{
    float: left;
    margin: 0 7px 10px 0;
}

.ui-dialog #emailGrupoSetor
{
    font-style: italic;
}
```

**layout.css**

```
#form #usuario
{
    position: absolute;
    height: 84px;
    top: 0;
    margin-right: 10px;
    right: 0;
    font-size: 105%;
    color: #608a66;
}

#form #usuario div
{
    height: 84px;
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#form #barraTitulo
{
    color: white;
    font-size: 130%;
    font-weight: bold;
    background-color: #6f9b76;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 2px 10px;
}

#form #barraTitulo a
{
    float: right;
    color: white;
    font-size: 75%;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: underline;
}

#form #conteudo
{
    margin: 5px 10px;
    min-height: 750px;
}
```

**acessonegado.css**

```
#conteudo p
{
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 180%;
}

#conteudo p:first-of-type
{
    /* Comment the margin-top attribute and the height of the #conteudo div will change. It shouldn't. */
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#conteudo p:last-of-type
{
    margin: 0;
    color: #004182;
}
```

Comment: That's exactly how `min-height` works; the `div` will always be 700px high unless the combined height of its children is more than 700px. Do you have any other styles declared that may affect the height of this `div`, such as `padding`? Can you provide the actual CSS used for the `div`?

Comment: It could be because wrong usage of the position properties. Can you share the complete snippet?

Comment: Can you create an example, if I understand your question correctly, min-height is what you want

Comment: I think it stays `700px` https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/233/

Comment: But if you want to use `padding` use `box-sizing: border-box`. Bootstrap adds that property https://jsfiddle.net/2Lzo9vfc/235/

Comment: If you could post the relevant css it could help, as it might be a syntax error ( ie, forgetting to add 'px' and just putting 700).

Comment: @JesseKernaghan That's not the case

Comment: @Marcos I'm sure it's not, but it's difficult to know anything without the corresponding code. Posting it will help us help you.

Comment: @JesseKernaghan I updated my question with some code.

Comment: There was a problem with the html I posted. It was missing the closing `</head>` and the open `<body>`

Answer (score 0):

Using `min-height` works just fine. see fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1g1pdqbc/6/

```
div {
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
    width: 100px;
}
```

The both divs are set to `min-height: 100px` but the second div has extra stuff in it and makes it taller.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I do think that I have to check my project better to see if there's something that is affecting the correct behavior for min-height. I think that I have already used it in the past in another project and it worked. I just don't know what could possible be affecting it.

Comment: Yes, if you share your CSS. we can then identify where the collision is. Something is overriding it.

Comment: There was a problem with the html I posted. It was missing the closing `</head>` and the open `<body>`

Comment: No, Adam. The tags were missing only in the code posted here (a copy and paste error), not on the actual application. I'm still with the same strange problem. I also added some comment to the last css file posted here to help spot the error.

Comment: I was playing around a little with my code and I think that the problem is that min-height doesn't ignore the margin attribute. For example, if I change my code above from `margin-top: 150px;` to `padding-top: 150px;` the min-height attribute work as expected (I mean, the content will not stretch without necessity). Can anyone confirm this?

Comment: Oh gotcha, I will look at it now.

Comment: @Marcos See this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/1g1pdqbc/9/ is this what you were going for? If so, your `margin-top: 150px` for your p tag is what was causing your problem, I changed it to `padding-top: 150px` instead.

Comment: Yes, I also noticed that changing from `margin-top` to `padding-top` fix the problem. So, I think that it means that `min-height` doesn't work well with margins or it is made to work this way, right?

Comment: @Marcos no it means that your were using `margin-top` incorrectly. Think of margin as and outside the div measurement, and padding as an inside the div measurement. If you had another `<p>` tag above the current `<p>` tag then you could use the `margin-top` because it would give the margin between the two tags. See fiddle, I made the example red so that you can see it http://jsfiddle.net/1g1pdqbc/10/

Comment: Thank you for the nice explanation and example. Now I understand what was going on.

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful

```
<div style = "min-height:100px; background-color:gray" id="content">
   div with 100px height
</div>

<br/>

<div style = "min-height:100px; background-color:gray" id="content">
       div with 100px height
    <div style = "min-height:100px; background-color:blue" id="content">
      inner div with 100px height
    </div>

    <div style = "min-height:100px; background-color:green" id="content">
      inner div  3 with 100px height
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: From w3schools]